# Sinon jquery stubbing

Tags: jquery, mocha.js, sinon, jsdom

There are a bunch of great blogs (like [Kumar's use of Sinon](http://blog.revathskumar.com/2013/03/testing-jquery-ajax-with-mocha-and-sinon.html) that explains how Sinon can stub jquery.

However, in that particular blog by Kumar as with others there is a simple jquery (npm) require:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

But jquery lives in the browser and needs a handle to a window.  Installed jsdom (plus python for Windows to handle a dependency) and set jquery correctly (otherwise there are no ajax methods etc on the **$** variable):

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom')
var $ = require('jquery')(jsdom.jsdom().defaultView);
```

Is this the only way to stub jquery?  jsdom is great but the extra (despite simple) catch of installing python breaks my automatic "testing" and involves a bunch of extra configuration on the build server.   Nothing impossible or hard just wondering why people gloss over in blogs that jquery when running testing (via Mocha) with Sinon is going to need access to a window to work?

Anybody attacking the problem in another way to stub jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a test suite involving `jsdom`, `mocha`, and `sinon` for client-side javascript (coffeescript actually, but your question is in JS). I got around the issue of requiring jQuery by having `jsdom` load it instead. Note that I have not tested what I have below, but it's based on my own setup. In place of `'path/to/jquery'` below, I actually load a single concatenated JS file which includes all external dependencies and my entire application code. The below example is from my `spec_helper` file, which is the first file that `mocha` runs.

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var sinon = require('sinon');
var _ = require('underscore');
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(require('sinon-chai'));
chai.should();

before(function(next){
  var config = {
    html: '<body></body>',
    scripts: ['path/to/jquery'],
    features: {
      FetchExternalResources: ['script'],
      ProcessExternalResources: ['script']
    },
    // Equivalent to document.ready event, so you know the DOM 
    // has loaded and `jQuery` is available on `window`.
    done: function(error, window) {
      // Exposes everything on `window` to `global` so its available
      // in your test suites
      _(global).defaults(window);

      next();
    }
  };

  // Creates the JSDom instance
  jsdom.env(config);
});

beforeEach(function(){
  this.sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
  this.clock = this.sandbox.useFakeTimers();
  this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
});

afterEach(function(){
  this.sandbox.restore();
  this.server.restore();
});
```

The idea is that you let `jsdom` control anything to do with `window`, and expose said `window` to `global` within your tests. You should now be able to stub jQuery as Kumar does in the blog post you linked to. I'm actually about to work on trying that right now, so I'll post here if I find any issues with this or any workarounds. As it stands, apparently `sinon.fakeServer` does not work with `jsdom` and `mocha` - see [here](https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS/issues/319) - so stubbing the ajax method is your best bet. Apparently `fakeServer` and `node` is a goal for Sinon v2.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The OP is reluctant to use jsdom because it means having to install Python on the test server. How is your answer actually helping with *this specific issue*?

Comment: That's fair. I guess I misunderstood the question. I thought OP was trying to load jQuery and use it without relying on `require`.

Comment: @grammar, Trying to avoid jsdom simply due to the python dependency which breaks automatic setup.  jsdom is killer but the manual step with python is a downer.  thought it odd that so many people sidesteps the window argument (from things like jsdom) when requiring jquery and then stubbing.

Comment: Yeah I hear that. The python dep was no issue for me being on a mac, but I know its a hinderance on windows. I had a bit of a hard time getting things working with `jsdom`, partly because I was also trying to incorporate `coffee-coverage` with it. Another possibility for you might be trying [mocha-phantomjs](https://github.com/metaskills/mocha-phantomjs). With that you can use an actual `html` file that loads `jQuery`, `sinon`, and your application without the need for tricky `window` workarounds.